# Adding Watermark/Text over Image in Flutter - Dart

Tags: android, image, flutter, dart, package

I am trying to add Text on image and then saving it to gallery.

Code:

```
    _originalImage = File(pickedFile.path);
    ui.Image Img = ui.decodeImage(_originalImage.readAsBytesSync());
    ui.drawString(Img, ui.arial_24, 100, 120, 'Add Text');
    List<int> wmImage = ui.encodeJpg(Img);
    _watermarkedImage = File.fromRawPath(Uint8List.fromList(wmImage));
```

But this throws an error:

> FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = ???

I am fetching Images from ImagePicker (Camera) Source.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RepaintBoundary with a global key. This is just a sample code to give you an idea . Here is the video link that might be helpful  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jljv7yNzqJw

```
  takeScreenshot() async {
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
    globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
print(pngBytes);
File imgFile = new File('$directory/screenshot${rng.nextInt(200)}.png');
setState(() {
  _imageFile = imgFile;
});
_savefile(_imageFile);
//saveFileLocal();
imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
```

}

Comment: After using RepaintBoundary , I'm getting this issue - Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.app1/app_flutter/screenshot56.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)